# Wrap a chosen category name with div

Tags: categories, taxonomy

I'm trying to wrap a category name in a post with a div. This is how i get the category name I need.

Reference Links :

- [`get_term_by`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)
- [`term_exists`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists)

My Ideas

```
 <?php $term = term_exists('foo', 'category'); ?>
 <?php $term = get_term_by('name', 'foo', 'category') ?>
```

I need to wrap `$term` in a div. But I still can't figure it how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_term_by` returns an object by default, so you could output the term name using

```
<?php 
    $term = get_term_by('name', 'foo', 'category');
    echo "<div>$term->name</div>";
 ?>
```