# Style a category from category list

Tags: categories, taxonomy

This is my previous question [Wrap a chosen category name with div](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185458/wrap-a-chosen-category-name-with-div) which I made a mistake on the question, however I got the correct answer. But thats not what I needed.

Currently, I'm using this code to get the category list for a single post.

```
<div>
    <?php $categories_list = get_the_category_list(__(' , ', 'theme')); ?>
    <?php printf(__('%1$s', 'xBlog'), $categories_list); ?> 
</div>
```

which outputs :

> foo, foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4

How do I wrap foo1 in a div? so I can only style that particular category name.

First Attempt

```
    <?php $categories_list = get_the_category_list(__(' / ', 'theme')); 
    $category_name = 'foo1';
    if($categories_list){
    foreach($categories_list as $category) 
    {
        if ( $category_name == $category->cat_name) 
       {
              $output .='<div class="category-custom-class">'.$category->cat_name.'</div>';
       }
       else
       {
             $output .='<div class="category-custom-class1">'.$category->cat_name.'</div>';
       }
}
    }
    ?>
    <?php printf(__(' %1$s', 'theme'), $categories_list); ?>
```

Getting Error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: `get_the_category_list()` returns a string, not an array, that is why you get the error. Try using `wp_get_post_terms()` or `get_the_category()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try looping to match the category name you need.

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$category_name = 'foo1'; // set this to the category name you want to show
$output = '';
if($categories){
foreach($categories as $category) 
{
        if ( $category_name == $category->cat_name) 
       {
              $output .='<div class="category-custom-class">'.$category->cat_name.'</div>';
       }
       else
       {
             $output .='<div class="category-custom-class1">'.$category->cat_name.'</div>';
       }
}
echo $output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the category order may change in the future. I don't think this is a good solution.

Comment: Code is updated now. Please check if this is what you needed.

Comment: Please check my edits, I'm getting error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" I still have no idea how this works.

Comment: This will not work, `get_the_category_list` returns a string, not an array

Comment: Try using `get_the_category` and update the results. @DroidBeginner